# How to get the exit code of the command in bat file in java

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a bat file which contains a single command. In java when I execute a command it returns 1 exit code and its correct. When I execute a bat file in java it returns an exit code 0.

How can I execute bat file but get a command exit code in java?

Following is the java code. bat file is in remote server.

```
String command = "wmic /node:some_ip /user:\"username\" /password:pass process call create \"\\\\some_ip\\Temp\\test_dir\\command.bat\"";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "cmd", "/C", command }, null);
int exitval = process.waitFor();
```

Comment: can you show your bat file and java codes?

Comment: Please search and read before asking, as SO is meant to be an archive of *useful* questions and answers. Also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a guide on how to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%` at the end of the batch file to the return error code to the caller.

Comment: Thank you for replay, but it didn't work. I tried to echo %ERRORLEVEL% and get it with 
String output = IOUtils.toString(process.getInputStream());
  System.out.println(output);
but getting the following output:

Executing (Win32_Process)->Create()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
 ProcessId = 7608;
 ReturnValue = 0;
};

Answer (score 0):

you can use  this as exit
EXIT [/B] [value ]
value        The numeric exit code to return.
 Also you can use quit
QUIT [value ]
value   The numeric exit code to return to TCC or to the previous batch file.